# How to extract the signature of a transaction using bitcoinj

Tags: transactions, signature, bitcoinj

I am trying to extract the signatures from a transaction. What is the best way to do this given a `com.google.bitcoin.core.Transaction` object I just received from the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for P2PK, and P2PKH, but multisig will not work.

```
int index = (the index you want);
List<TransactionInput> inputs = Transaction.getInputs()
TransactionInput input = inputs.get(index);
Script scriptSig = input.getScriptSig();
List<ScriptChunk> signature_and_pubkey = scriptSig.getChunks();
ScriptChunk sig_chunk = signature_and_pubkey.get(0);
bytes[] sig_bytes = sig_chunk.data;
```

If you want a TransactionSignature object instead of raw bytes:

```
TransactionSignature ts = TransactionSignature.decodeFromBitcoin(sig_bytes, false)
```

Comment: how can I get a `TransactionSignature` object from this? I tried `com.google.bitcoin.crypto.TransactionSignature.decodeFromBitcoin(sig_chunk.data, false)` but sometimes it gives an error.

Comment: @Jus12 RuntimeError or VerificationError?

Comment: Here is the error I got (happens in few cases only): 
`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: DER length more than 4 bytes: 112
at com.google.bitcoin.core.ECKey$ECDSASignature.decodeFromDER(ECKey.java:358)`